# Finding the longest word given a trie dictionary and letters

Tags: c++, search, dictionary, trie

For a word-building game I'm working on, I have a trie that stores every possible word from a dictionary. That's about 179,000 at the moment.

The way the game works, there's a 5x5 (or possibly larger in the future, depending on how efficient the solution to this question turns out to be) grid of letters. The player and the PC take turns making words from those letters, getting points based on the letters and length of the words (the letter valuations are similar to Scrabble, but that's not important). Whenever a player makes a word, those letters are removed from the board, and this continues until no words can be made, at which point the grid is reset (and the winner of the round gets a bonus).

The question is this: given a 5x5 grid of letters and that dictionary trie, how can I efficiently determine either the longest word that can be made or a list of all possible words? Note that the letters don't need to be touching each other to be used; any of the grid's letters are fine.

The only way I can think is to essentially do a BFS on the trie, pruning it when the next letter isn't in the grid, but that doesn't seem very efficient to me as it'd have to be tried for each letter in the grid. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried the brute force approach and was performance unacceptable?

Comment: Given the operations you want to perform, are you sure a trie is the appropriate data structure to use?

Comment: @Pete: I haven't tried it, but it would be factorial time. The initial, full 5x5 grid has on the order of 25! possibilities to check--way too inefficient.

Comment: @ct_: I'm not 100% sure, but it's the best I could think of...any other suggestions?

Comment: @DanielBurnett I don't think in reality the brute force approach would be anywhere near 25! - you wouldn't expect to have very many 25 letter words.  Surely the algorithm isn't hard to write to test it - at least it gives a worst case benchmark to test other schemes against and also offers a reference for testing their correctness.

Answer (score 0):

Finding the "best" word will always require some searching in the trie. But a trie isn't a terrible structure for doing this.

However, you will have to do something like:

1. Pick a letter from your board.
2. Find the node in the trie for the current "word".
3. Pick another letter on the board.
4. Repeat from step 2 until: no word can be found or out of letters on the board.
5. Remember the "score" for the word you found.
6. Repeat this process for all (unique?) starting letters on the board.

You may want to check if your have "tried this sequence before", but I'm not sure that is much benefit.

To make it reasonably fair on the competitor competing against the computer, you may want to limit the number of attempts the computer makes, simply because the human probably won't ever win against the computer in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with an algorithm which performs *O(n)* operations throughout the entire game, where *n* is the size of the dictionary. It uses additional data structures though, and in all likelihood the simple bruteforce would suffice. If performance does turn out to be an issue, read on.

Consider the set of words that can be produced using the letters on the board. Words will get removed from this set throughout the game as letters are removed from the board.

The initial set of words can be determined by scanning through the dictionary. Words whose letters form a subset of the letters on the board are valid. There are many ways to test for this, such as comparing the sorted letters of the word to the sorted letters of the board or creating letter frequency tables and comparing them.

When a letter is removed, words in which the letter occurs the same number of times as it did on the board prior to the letter's removal have to be removed from the set. For example, if the board had two *e*'s and one is removed, only words that have exactly two *e*'s need to be removed from the set.

The set of words can be maintained efficiently using a linked list. For constant time access to the word with the highest score the list can be sorted at the start using an *O(n)* sorting algorithm such as [pigeonhole sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_sort). Deleting nodes from the list will not disturb the order.

For efficient deletion of all words with a certain letter frequency, references to the nodes of the linked list are stored in a two dimensional array. Entry *(x, n)* of the array contains references to all the nodes whose words have exactly *n* occurrences of letter *x*.

For example, references to the node containing the word *"eye"* will be stored at entries *('e', 2)* and *('y', 1)* of the array. When there are two *e*'s on the board and one is removed, all the nodes in entry *('e', 2)* are removed from the linked list. If a word has already been removed it is ignored.

Removing a node from the linked list is done in constant time, and each word can be removed at most once in the entire game (and may have at most 25 additional removal attempts), making the entire process *O(n)*.

Comment: I never thought of doing it this way! I'll test it out when I get a chance, but it seems like it should work. Thanks!